# How to find versions of various HAL in Android L?

Tags: android

I learned from a conversation that Android HAL versions change (due to code re-factor and new features) from release to release. How can I list all the release version numbers of different HALs in Android L release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from other forums I took to looking through the code @ https://source.android.com/devices/halref/files.html. I think HAL versions for respective HAls are:

1. Display: hwcomposer_defs.h (HWC_DEVICE_API_VERSION_1_4)
2. Audio: audio.h (AUDIO_DEVICE_API_VERSION_3_0)
3. Sensors: sensors.h (SENSORS_DEVICE_API_VERSION_1_3)
4. Power: power.h (POWER_MODULE_API_VERSION_0_3)

Can someone confirm? Though I need clarity about the camera, lights, GPS.